# Google Chrome Extension + Login with Facebook + Parse

Tags: facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a google chrome extension, a use case requires that users can login with Facebook and share via a post to their Facebook wall.

The correct application flow would be as such:

1. User click google chrome extension - summons extension page
2. User clicks "login with facebook" on the extension page (or in a new tab) the users then see the "approve app" from Facebook
3. The user approves the app
4. The user is directed to a new page that thanks them for installing and processes all the needed user information  OR  the user is sent back to the google chrome extension (better way)
5. If the user is not sent back to the google chrome extension, they should be told to do so, but at this point how to get the data to the google chrome extension?
6. The user opens to the Google chrome extension, they should now see "Hi John" or similar instead of "Login with Facebook"
7. The user can no post to Facebook

My major hick-ups are logging in with Facebook, and getting the data back to the extension.

I've created a Facebook app, done most of the coding specific to the app, I'm trying to keep the app just javascript (but I can add in php if there is no other way), tried using the standard Facebook javascript, and tried using the desktop client for Facebook.

Anyone else gone through this process of connecting Google Chrome Extensions and Facebook login before?

As a final note, I'm trying to with with Parse for this project, so if you have any extra insite on that it would be great too!

---

A good example of what I'm trying to accomplish is similar to what Any.do 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/any.do?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had this kind of problem lately ;). It's a bit complicated, but I'll try to explain it in the simplest way.

Put somewhere in your extension (maybe options page) link "login with facebook" that redirects to: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<APP_ID>&response_type=token&scope=<PERMISSIONS>&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

When someone clicks on this link, will be asked to give permissions, etc (facebook page). If someone would agree, the page will load: `http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` with parameters `access_token` and `expires_in` in address.

Now, background page should have script like this:

```
var successURL = 'www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';

function onFacebookLogin(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { // get all tabs from every window
      for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tabs[i].url.indexOf(successURL) !== -1) {
          // below you get string like this: access_token=...&expires_in=...
          var params = tabs[i].url.split('#')[1];

          // in my extension I have used mootools method: parseQueryString. The following code is just an example ;)
          var accessToken = params.split('&')[0];
          accessToken = accessToken.split('=')[1];

          localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
          chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onFacebookLogin);
```

And this is how you get access token from facebook. Now you can send requests to https://graph.facebook.com.

Hope I helped ;)

Comment: Marcin, thanks for responding.  I was doing something similar, I've implemented with your suggestions, but for some reason the access token is always considered in active.  I've cleared out the Facebook app from the user profile, and authorize the app, but the returned access token is invalid.  Is this because of the process you suggested, or is there another step?

Comment: Marcin, after a bit more work I found the rest of the solution, I was not calling the proper url.  The correct URL to call (for reference) is `https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Comment: Great to hear, I am glad you were able to solve this issue ;)

Comment: Hello Marcin, what's the facebook apps settings for you? Because it always gives me a error: "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: Hello Marcin, I have tried this and it redirects me to browser new tab but I want ot open new facebook popup window from my extension popup for the facebook login. Do you know any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question (Don't have enough credit to comment).

In your Facebook developer settings, click the advanced tab at the top, make sure "Client OAuth login" & "Embedded browser OAuth login" are both moved to "Yes" and then I had to add "http://www.facebook.com/" to the Valid OAuth redirect URI's

Answer (score -1):

now facebook has changed "Client Oauth Login" button location. You need to add a product and after adding facebook login you will found here

[image]