# How to build a Chrome Extension that uses Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I want to build a Chrome extension that uses Facebook Login. I found [this article from 2012](http://brianmayer.com/2012/12/building-a-chrome-extension-that-connects-to-a-facebook-app/) on Google, but that's about it. There is also this from StackOverflow: [Google Chrome Extension + Login with Facebook + Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537275/google-chrome-extension-login-with-facebook-parse) which uses what seems like a workaround: go through all the user's tabs, and look for the login success and access token.

Are there any better / cleaner ways to do this?

Comment: Check this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2